# cc_import for debug and release versions?

Tags: dll, bazel

My toolset:

- Windows 10 x64 (1909)
- Bazel 3.1.0
- Visual Studio 2019 (16.6)
- Powershell

I need to use a prebuild third-party C++ DLL. The third-party lib looks like this:

```
<directory> third-party-lib
├── <directory> bin
|   ├── <file> third_party_lib.dll
|   └── <file> third_party_libd.dll
├── <directory> lib
|   ├── <file> third_party_lib.lib
|   └── <file> third_party_libd.lib
└── <directory> includes
    └── <file> third_party_lib.h
```

So there are two versions a release and a debug version. Filenames ending with "d" indicate the debug version.

To consume this library I am using a `cc_import` target:

```
cc_import(
    name = "third-party-lib",
    interface_library = "lib/third_party_lib.lib",
    shared_library = "bin/third_party_lib.dll",
)
```

My build target depends on the `third-party-lib`. Building in release (opt) mode works without any problems:

```
bazel build //:MyBuildTarget
```

But if I try to do a debug build I run into linker problems:

```
bazel build --compilation_mode=dbg //:MyBuildTarget
```

Is there any possibility to specify debug and release DLLs in `cc_import` rule? Or is there any other rule that can I use for this propose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [select()](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/configurable-attributes.html) to switch between library variants:

```
cc_import(
    name = "third-party-lib",
    interface_library = "lib/third_party_lib.lib",
    shared_library = select({
        ":debug_build": "third_party_libd.dll",
        "//conditions:default": "third_party_lib.dll",
    }),
)

config_setting(
    name = "debug_build",
    values = {
        "compilation_mode": "dbg",
    },
)
```